# why can't I connect ubuntu 19.04 installed on windows 10 Hyper-v to the internet?

Tags: windows-10, 19.04, hyper-v

I quick installed ubuntu on windows 10 hyper-v, it has a default virtual network adapter along with the virtual switch but it doesn't want to connect to the internet.

Comment: I am having the same issue with Hyper-V and Ubuntu 19.04. Were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old but deserves an answer.

- Go to network adapters and settings
- Right click the adapter that is giving you internet
- Click properties
- Click the tab Sharing
- Check the box allow other network users to connect through this computers internet connection

Doing this will also give your machine a 192.168 address instead of a 172.17

I am assuming, by default, it will not let you connect to the outside world, unless you choose external. I usually create an internal adapter, apply these settings, give it the IP address range I want through powershell. Then give the vm a static IP address.

Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: To clarify:

- Add virtual switch (internal) in Hyper-V manager

- Add to VM

- Configure sharing options in host network settings